# Custom Expressible Protocol To Implement Implicit Construction In Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

AFAIK, Swift `class` can be assigned by literal value by conform to `ExpressibleBy*Literal` .

For example, class A can be assigned by `Int` like this, which is similar to implicit construction in `C++`

```
class A : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int

    required init(integerLiteral value: A.IntegerLiteralType) {
    }
}

var a: A = 1
```

Now, can I extended `ExpressibleBy*` protocol to any my custom type ?

```
protocol ExpressibleByMyTypeLiteral {
    associatedtype MyType

    init(literal value: Self.MyType) 
}

class B {
}

class A : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, ExpressibleByMyTypeLiteral {
    //ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int

    required init(integerLiteral value: A.IntegerLiteralType) {
    }

    //ExpressibleByMyTypeLiteral
    typealias MyType = B

    required init(literal value: A.MyType) {
    } 
}

var a: A = 1
var aMyType: A = B() //Compiler Error: Cannot convert value of 'B' to specified type 'A'
```

Comment: No, this isn't possible, since all of the *Literal protocols are baked into the compiler with support. Besides, `B()` is not a literal but a value constructed at runtime; Swift doesn't support custom conversions like C++ does — it uses explicit initializers instead.

Comment: I too long for this features, we could write amazing code with custom `ExpressibleBy*Literal` protocols.